# word2vec -storing a word and its vector yet be able to efficiently run k-nearest neighbour

Tags: databases, word2vec

After training a model using word2vec I'd now like to store the trained model with the word serving as a key and the vector as its value. However I'm not sure how I'll be able to implement in this way a k-nearest neighbour search. What would be the correct way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A most popular way of obtaining the *approximate* nearest neighbors is the [locality sensitive hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#LSH_algorithm_for_nearest_neighbor_search). And [here](https://erikbern.com/2015/07/04/benchmark-of-approximate-nearest-neighbor-libraries/) are some practical results. Then once you have the neighboring keys, it's straightforward to use a key-value store to retrieve the corresponding words.